# Можно чуть подробнее про невозможность следующего кода: if(iOb instanceof Gen<Integer>)

Tags: java

Я слышал, что во время рантайма все дженерики преобразуются к обычным типам. Я не до конца понимаю, как это происходит, возможно поэтому и не понимаю, почему следующий код вызывает ошибку компиляции:

```
class Gen<T> {
    T ob;

    Gen(T o) {
        ob = o;
    }
}

public class GenHierarchy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Gen<Integer> iOb = new Gen<Integer>(88);
        if (iOb instanceof Gen<Integer>)
            System.out.println("iOb2 is instance of Gen2<Integer>");
    }
}
```

Я полагал, что как раз-таки после удаления сведений о том, что класс Gen обобщенный, мы получим простейший случай необобщенного класса и его экземпляра. Мне кажется JVM должно быть еще понятнее. Понимаю, что ошибаюсь. Но не понимаю, из-за чего реально проблема. Почему такую элементарную на первый взгляд зависимость в рантайме нельзя проверить?

Answer (score 2):

Информация о параметре обобщенного типы действительно стирается во время исполнения. Это значит, что код который сгенерирует компилятор (не считая проверки, которая синтаксически некорректная, но об этом дальше) будет таким:

```
class Gen {
    Object ob;

    Gen(Object o) {
        ob = o;
    }
}

public class GenHierarchy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Gen iOb = new Gen(88);
        ...
    }
}
```

На этапе компиляции, компилятор дополнительно проверит, что в выражении `new Gen(88)` аргумент может быть приведен к параметру указанному вместо `T`, т.е. к `Integer`. Именно это суть обобщенных типов - компилятор делает дополнительную проверку, в данном случае, что вы в программе используете объект типа совместимого с типом generic-a. И если в программе использующей обобщенные типы нет ни одного предупреждения компилятора, то гарантируется, что во время исполнения вы никогда не получите `ClassCastException`.

Во время же выполнения, если посмотрите на код выше, нет никакой информации о том, что реально хранится в `iOb`. Можно возразить "есть же поле `ob`" - но в общем случае это не работает, т.к. у вас необязательно будет поле с типом параметра generic-а, или в таком поле, даже если оно есть, может храниться `null`, и тогда опять же реальный тип взять неоткуда.

Более того, путем явного приведения типов и игнорирования предупреждений компилятора, вы можете в `iOb` засунуть любой тип:

```
Gen<Integer> iOb = new Gen<Integer>(88);
((Gen)iOb).ob = new String("aaa");
```

Именно поэтому, проверка так как вы ее хотите написать `iOb instanceof Gen<Integer>` не имеет смысла, и является синтаксически неправильной.

Проверять можно либо так `iOb instaceof Gen`, либо так `iOb.ob instanceOf Integer`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь развернутый комментарий! Теперь действительно все стало понятно.