# Подставление типа для дженерика

Tags: java, generics

Изучаю дженерики. Возник такой вопрос, поскольку на момент компиляции стираются типы, и компилятор их видит, как объекты типа Object, из-за чего накладывается много ограничений на использование дженериков из-за `RuntimeException`, мне не понятно, в какой момент эти самые типы подставляются на свое место

Comment: Например, если вы напишете `List<Integer>`, в скомпилированном виде будет `List<Number>`

Comment: Тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1298419/218971 есть ответ на очень похожий вопрос и там это рассматривается подробно. Не уверен, возможно, даже стоит этот вопрос сделать дубликатом, так как ответ будет очень похожим.

Comment: @insolor почему же не стирается? Речь о [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Стирается в том смысле, что условный `List<Integer>` в скомпилированном коде представлен как `List<Object>`, т.е.  информация о типе `Integer` "стерлась".

Comment: @Elizaveta, разве не к ```Object``` все приводится?

Comment: @Gleb да, ошиблась)